# the existence of a maximun for $f(X)$ don't depend on *all* topologies of X

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact topological space, and $Y$ a topological space under the order topology. Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous function under these topologies. Then, $f(X)$ has largest and smallest elements (*), by the extreme value theorem.

If I endow $X$ with other topology for which $f$ is not continuous or $X$ is not compact, it seems not to influence the fact (*), about $f(X)$, which I can assert for the first topology of X. So, is it sufficient to find **one** topology that fulfills compactness and continuity to assert the fact (*), or is there some detail that I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a set $X$, a linearly ordered space $Y$ with the order topology, and a function $f:X\to Y$, and you want to know whether the following statement is true:

> If there is a topology on $X$ that makes $X$ compact and $f$ continuous, then $f[X]$ has a largest and a smallest element in the order on $Y$.

Yes, this is true. If there is such a topology on $X$, $f[X]$ is a compact subset of $Y$ and therefore must have a maximum and a minimum element.

This is not a necessary condition, however. Let $Y=[0,1)\cup(1,2]$ with the order topology, let $X=Y$, and let $f$ be the identity map. Then $f[X]$ has both a maximum and a minimum element, but there is no topology on $X$ that makes $X$ compact and $f$ continuous: if there were such a topology, $Y$ would be compact, and it isn’t.